# gamequery collision detection doesnt react

Tags: gamequery

i created 2 sprite objects and want to check if they collide, but it doesnt seem to work.

**My code:**

**creation of the sprites:****

```
.addGroup("flying", {width: 366, height: 254})

.addSprite("flyinganimation",{animation: flight, 
                  posx: 0, posy: 0, width: 366, height: 254})

.addGroup("obstacles",  {width: 169, height: 67})

.addSprite("obstaclenames", {animation: obstacleimage,
            width: 169,height: 67,
            posx: 300,
            posy: 400})
```

**looped code in the callback function:****

```
var collision = $("#flying,.group").collision("#obstacles,.group");

if (collision > 0)
{
 document.write ("collision");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two potential problems here:
1) collision() returns a jQuery object so you will need to do a .size() in order to retrieve the number of collisions
2) you should apply collision() to only one object.

To sum up your first line should look like this:

```
var collision = $("#flying").collision("#obstacles,.group").size();
```